# Grouping order depands on product in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

example data is

```
orderid  productid
1            1
1            2
1            3
2            2
2            3
3            1
4            3
4            2
5            1
6            2
7            2
8            1
8            2
```

the result is

```
 odcnt  orderid  productid
    2    3         1
    2    5         1
    2    6         2
    2    7         2
    2    2         2
    2    2         3
    2    4         2
    2    4         3
    1    8         1
    1    8         2
    1    1         1
    1    1         2
    1    1         3
```

Comment: Where does odcnt column come from?

Comment: order and product match count in total. like product 1 have only two order in single odcnt is 2, and for multiple like order 2 and 4 have same item and two order same for multiple...

Answer (score 0):

this is what you are looking for

```
select count(*) as odcnt,  orderid,  productid from Table
    group by orderid,  productid
```

Comment: I don't think it's correct, all count = 1 if you `group by orderid, productid`

Comment: as he wants result like this... otherwise elaborate the problem

Comment: he should tell when odcnt=2 or when it will be 1

Comment: See his comment also below his question

Comment: It is still not clear. I try this query, it returns the same order with his expected out, but i could not calculate odcnt `SELECT * 
FROM @SampleData sd
ORDER BY count(*) OVER(PARTITION BY sd.orderid) `

Comment: try this {SELECT count(*) OVER(PARTITION BY sd.orderid) odcnt,* FROM @SampleData sd ORDER BY count(*) OVER(PARTITION BY sd.orderid)}

Answer (score 0):

You need details of multiple product and its count. If you are using any programming language then you can easily implement but with the sql you need multiple commands. some thing like

```
SELECT COUNT(`orderid`) as 'odcnt',`orderid`,`productid` FROM `order` WHERE `productid`=1;
SELECT COUNT(`orderid`) as 'odcnt',`orderid`,`productid` FROM `order` WHERE `productid`=2;
SELECT COUNT(`orderid`) as 'odcnt',`orderid`,`productid` FROM `order` WHERE `productid`=3;
```

(Try above command in nested query, but i'm not sure..)